# PHP/MySQL - Calculate Profit by Adding Up Sales and Purchases then Subtracting

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a PHP application with a MySQL database which stores a list of transactions which have been made by a company.

These sales and purchases are held in the same table with an identifier column with either a p or s in it.

I'm looking to calculate the profit by taking all the transactions where salesOrPurchase = 's' and adding them all up, then doing the same for salesOrPurchase = 'p', then subtracting our purchases from our sales to work out the profit.

Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
SUM(amount) WHERE salesOrPurchase = 's' as SalesTotal,
SUM(amount) WHERE salesOrPurchase = 'p' as PurchasesTotal,
(SalesTotal - PurchasesTotal) as Profit
FROM transactions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a subquery?

```
SELECT SalesTotal, PurchasesTotal, (SalesTotal-PurchasesTotal) as Profit
FROM (SELECT (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM transactions WHERE salesOrPurchase = 's') as SalesTotal,
             (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM transactions WHERE salesOrPurchase = 'p') as PurchasesTotal
     ) t
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks!
How would I change this if I wanted to also allow it to be filtered by year, e.g. the profit made in 2010?
Is it possible just to add another WHERE statement for date = 'xx-xxx-10'?

Comment: Use AND after 's'/'p' and then put `date = 'xx-xxx-10`, I would type it out but I'm on my iPhone. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Got it working using wildcards and some input taken from my PHP. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use alias in the same `select` where they are defined.  Instead, use conditional aggregation for all three:

```
SELECT SUM(case when salesOrPurchase = 's' then amount end) as SalesTotal,
       SUM(case when salesOrPurchase = 'p' then amount end) as PurchasesTotal,
       SUM(case when salesOrPurchase = 's' then amount
                when salesOrPurchase = 'p' then - amount
           end)  as Profit
FROM transactions;
```